# Matlab - Using matrix as an index for array vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, allocation

I currently have a vector containing a cell array of predefined values. The number and content of these values should be able to vary:

```
names = {'r1','r2','r3'};
```

Furthermore, I have a Matrix, that should serve as an index Matrix. It looks like the following example, however, should also be variable in its size.

```
mat = [1 3 3; 2 1 3; 1 1 1];
```

Delivering:

```
 1  3  3 
 2  1  3 
 1  1  1
```

I would now like to create a matrix containing the respective values of the array in the same matrix format. Hence, whereever mat contains a 1 the output should contain the first value of names and so on. The final result should then look like:

```
r1  r3  r3 
r2  r1  r3 
r1  r1  r1
```

Just to avoid missunderstandings: The content of names simply serves as an example here. Later specific names should be matched and it cannot be solved by simply adding an r infront of every index value.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's simple:

```
result = names(mat);
```

The only caveat is that every numeric element in `mat` must be integer and between 1 and the number of elements in `names`.

*Explanation:* The `mat` works as a *linear index*. The general rule when indexing linearly is that the values are taken from the source array in column order (as it is normal), but the shape is the same as the shape of the index array.

**Later Edit**, thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo): this rule is valid except for the singleton dimensions of the index array. To enforce the rule for this corner case, one may use the *slightly* more elaborate (and more time-consuming) form:

```
result = reshape(names(mat), size(mat));
```

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I didn't see that. Perfect answer and thanks

Comment: This is very useful but very nasty [MATLAB behaviour] to people who still thinks that index is a number.

Comment: @CST-Link _the shape is the same as the shape of the index array_ Well, not always. If `mat` is a column vector and `names` is a row, `names(mat)` will be a row.  So your `reshape` may be needed after all :-)

Comment: @Crowley I'm not sure I understand your statement.  "Indexing" in the MATLAB universe is a very well documented term: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511

Comment: @rayryeng It may be well documented but is it also well known? If you think of Matlab as programming language you can easily get fooled by such unexpected behaviour. If you think of it as a mathematical tool that can, by the way, produce programs and keep this in mind, you won't be that surprised. Also, if one read manual,...

Comment: @Crowley I wouldn't call it "unexpected behaviour". It's one of the most useful mechanisms that MATLAB has to offer and it's one of the reasons why the language is popular.... and yes if one read the manual, or perhaps read StackOverflow :)

Comment: @LuisMendo My bad! Going to correct the answer, thanks for identifying the corner case

Comment: @rayryeng For someone who thinks an index is a number (scalar) it is surprise when they can use matrix as "index" - mostly to get part of the matrix. And yes, it is useful!

Comment: @Crowley oh hehe :) yes, I see where you're coming from now... and yes I do agree that it's a rather misnomer of terms!